# I used redux, but it doesn't work. Can I know where the problem is?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently making validation check of the input. I want to send the inspection result of input to another component by using redux. I made redux and connected it, but I couldn't find the value I wanted and the *undefined* value came out. I think there is a problem with using redux, but I don't know which part is the problem. I'm sorry that there are many codes and files because it's a redux question. But I don't know where to fix it. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where to fix it.

**EmailAction.jsx :***

This is an action file. I put Rudex's action in here

```
export const yesEmail = () => {
  return{
    type : 'True',
  }
} 

export const noEmail = () => {
  return{
    type : 'False',
  }
}
```

**SignUpEmail.jsx:**

This is the reducer file. I put the initial value and reducer in here.

```
const initailState = {
  isEmail : false
}

const SignUpEmail = (state=initailState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "True" : 
      return {
        ...state,
        isEmail : true
      }
      
    case "False" : 
      return {
        ...state,
        isEmail : false
      }

    default :
    return {
      ...state,
    }  
  }
}

export default SignUpEmail;
```

**index.js :**

And this is the root reducer file. These were the redux files.

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import SignUpEmail from "./SignUpEmail";



const rootRudcer = combineReducers(
  {
    SignUpEmail
  }
)

export default rootRudcer;
```

---

**SignUpLoginButton.jsx:**

I'd like to get a value in this file. I used the *useSelector* to get the desired value as `checkemail` and tested the value with console here, and the undefined value came out

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ButtonWrap = styled.button`
  background-color: rgba(0, 149, 246 , .3);
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
`

function SignUpLoginButton({email, name, userName, passWord}) {

  const checkEMail = useSelector (state=>state.SignUpEmail.isEMail)

  console.log('checkEmail :',checkEMail)

  return (
    <ButtonWrap>
      <div>
        가입
      </div>
    </ButtonWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUpLoginButton;
```

**SignUpEmailInput:**

I used a `dispatch` here. I used `emailPhoneCheck` function to dispatch every time I receive a value from input. There is also a function for validation, but I think you just need to pass this part and look at the part that used dispatch!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const InputWrap = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`

function SignUpEmailInput({email, setEmail}) {

    const [isCorrectEmail, setIsCorrectEmail] = useState(false);
    const [isPhone,setIsPhone] = useState(false);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
    //use dispatch
    const emailPhoneCheck = (e) => {
      if(isCorrectEmail===true||isPhone===true) {
        dispatch({type:'True'})
      }
  
      else {
        dispatch({type:'False'})
      }
    }
    
  
  // check isCorrectEmail
  const onCheckEmail = (e) => {

    const regexEmail = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\.]?[0-9a-zA-Z])*@[0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\.]?[0-9a-zA-Z])*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/i
    const EmailInput = e.target.value

    if(regexEmail.test(EmailInput)) {
      setIsCorrectEmail(true)
    }

    else {
      setIsCorrectEmail(false)
    }

  }

  //check isPhone
  const onCheckPhone = (e) => {
    const regexPhone =  /^\d+$/
    const PhoneInput = e.target.value

    if(regexPhone.test(PhoneInput)&&PhoneInput.length>9) {
      setIsPhone(true)
    }

    else {
      setIsPhone(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <InputWrap isFocus={isFocus} isCorrectEmail={isCorrectEmail} isPhone={isPhone} inputLength={inputLength}>
      <label>
        <span>
          <input 
            value={email} 
            onChange={(e)=> {setEmail(e.target.value); onCheckEmail(e); onCheckPhone(e); emailPhoneCheck(e);}}/>
        </span>
      </label>
    </InputWrap>
  )
}

export default SignUpEmailInput;
```

**index.js:**

Lastly, I will upload the top file just in case. I'm so sorry I have so many files and codes

```
import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //구버전
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootRudcer from './store/reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(rootRudcer);


const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <Provider store={store} >
    <App/>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: would be better if you put all of them in a code sandbox or jsplayground and share the link

Comment: what does it show for `console.log(useSelector(state=>state))` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
The value comes out well as below! But 
`const checkEMail = useSelector (state=>state.SignUpEmail.isEMail)`
I don't think the path is wrong, but it's weird

**result:**
{SignUpEmail: {…}}
   SignUpEmail: {isEmail: false}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo at the isE**M**ail, it should be isE**m**ail

```
const checkEMail = useSelector (state=>state.SignUpEmail.isEMail)
```

And your **dispatch** is happening one life circle late. **emailPhoneCheck** function will not have the latest **isCorrectEmail** variable state as **setIsCorrectEmail** function will only affect in the next render. You should do all logic in one function if you don't need to wait for the next render for a particular reason. **dispatch(...)** should be moved to **onCheckEmail** function.

```
if(regexEmail.test(EmailInput)) {
  setIsCorrectEmail(true)
  dispatch({type:'True'})
}

else {
  setIsCorrectEmail(false)
  dispatch({type:'False'})
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for your reply...